# What is KeyError: 'twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer' (Python, youtube_dl)

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

I have been writing a Discord bot in Python using discord.py version 1.5.0. Only recently have I began adding music commands to it with youtube_dl, youtube_search, and ffmpeg. I can play the audio entirely, as well as pull titles, durations, thumbnails, etc. The only problem I have had thus far is that when I store the Youtube URL in a list and then index it on the "next" command then it returns an error saying "KeyError: 'twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer'" and I cannot find any other examples of this being returned back to the user. If someone could help me understand what the issue is then that would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

```
@bot.command()
    async def play(ctx, *args):
        #local variables
        global queueList
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voiceChannel = server.voice_client
        keywords = listtostring(args)
        results = ast.literal_eval(YoutubeSearch(keywords, max_results=1).to_json())
        test = results['videos']
        print(test[0])
        vidId = test[0]['id']
        vidThumbnail = test[0]['thumbnails'][0]
        vidUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(vidId)
        queueList.append(vidUrl)

        if args and ctx.message.author.voice:

            async with ctx.typing():

                player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queueList[0], loop=client.loop)
                await ctx.send("`{}` added to the queue!".format(player.title))

                try: 
                    voiceChannel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
                    nowPlaying = discord.Embed(
                        title = "Now playing",
                        description = "Now playing **{}**".format(player.title),
                        color = rupertColor
                    )
                    nowPlaying.set_thumbnail(url=vidThumbnail)

                    await ctx.send(embed = nowPlaying) #('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))
                except: 
                    print("failed playing")

                del(queueList[0])

        else:
            await stop(ctx)
            async with ctx.typing():
                player = await YTDLSource.from_url(str(queueList[0]), loop=client.loop)
                try: 
                    voiceChannel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
                    await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))
                except: 
                    print("failed playing")
                    queueList.append(vidUrl)

                del(queueList[0])
```

Comment: Can you add relevant code and the full stack trace?

Comment: You should provide example source code that demonstrates the problem you are getting.

Comment: Edited post to have the play command incorporated.

Comment: I figured out what it was. providing empty arguments cause an error in the results variable declaration before it could even get to the if statement. My bad